# ArcGIS Pro (Catalog Pane) will not make folder connection to external hard drive

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, connection, catalog-pane

I have an external hard drive that is storing spatial data and ESRI 10x projects. I would like to add this letter drive as a folder connect but ArcGIS Pro v2.9 seems unwilling or unable to do this.  I see from [this link](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/why-does-arcgis-pro-not-support-adding-folder/td-p/712570) that this feature was initially left off of the Pro version of Catalog but this post seems to claim this feature was implemented in 2.2.  It appears to have either not been implemented or retracted as I can add folders inside the drive but not the drive itself.

In ArcCatalog 10.x I could make connections to any letter drive, then when I used thumb drives or different hard drives it was easy to open them and sift through the data on them. I have a legacy of 10.x data and projects stored on drives and I do not want to have to make new folder connections to each project or data folder every time I plug in a different external storage device in my Pro project.

How do I make a folder connection to a drive letter in Pro?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a problem with connecting to folders over my works VPN from home, ArcGIS Pro will simply not add them using the method you are showing in your question. I think its more to do with the VPN than ArcGIS Pro.

What I discovered as a work around was to open up Windows file explorer and then drag 'n' drop the folder in question onto the Folders node in the Catalog Pane, then ArcGIS Pro makes the connection.

Comment: In my case the connection is via USB, or over a CiTRIX network, and not a VPN.  @Hornbydd 's workaround mapped to the letter drive in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

When i opened cataloge, i went to folder connection and just wrote the Name of folder (Extension) as same as in the image and pressed enter then the files appeared, and folders connected to external hardisk[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).